# PHP PDO Fetch row and print values

Tags: php, pdo

I couldn't understand the exact working of the fetch/fetchall in PDO.can i get a simple example for PDO fetch for fetching each row and displays its values iteratively?

Comment: you can get a simple example by using an internet search engine. serously, it's much more easy than asking here

Comment: [This well-known tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) puts PDO basic usage in context of `mysql_*()` usage, (with which you may be familiar already) so you can see how each fetch method is used in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of examples around.. You can do a simple fetch using a `while` loop too

```
<?php
//your PDO connection goes here.....
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT username FROM yourtable');

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['username'];
}
```

Read the PHP Manual on [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

---

By using a fetchAll , you can grab all the results in a single array..

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT username FROM yourtable");
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($results);
```

Read the PHP Manual on [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a query, you get a `PDOStatement` object. That object, once the query gets executed, will be populated with the results.

Now you are given two functions:

```
$pdoStatement->fetch();
```

and

```
$pdoStatement->fetchAll();
```

---

`fetch` will fetch one row at a time. It also advances automatically, so you don't need to call a `next()` function. Just call `fetch` in a loop, and you'll get all of your results. `fetch` returns an array.

`fetchAll` will fetch *all* of the rows at once. Returning an array of arrays (where each inner array is one row).